# Pandas: Counting totals for columns of a dataframe, based on whether two items in a row match

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to count certain values, as long as other values in a dataframe match. Here is an example of my df format, the real df has many more rows and columns. The only values I need to create counts for are `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`. There is no collection of values in any column/row combination.

```
df1 = 
item1   item2   item3   t1   t2   t3   ...
foo     foo     bar     a    a    b    ...
foo     bar     foo     c    a    c    ...
foo     bar     baz     a    b    c    ...
...     ...     ...     ...  ...  ...
```

The pseudocode I'm thinking is (for each row):

```
if df1[item1] = df1[item2]:
    add ONE to t if that column = 'a'
    add TWO to t if that column = 'b'
if df1[item1] = df1[item3]:
    add ONE to t if that column = 'c'
    add TWO to t if that column = 'd'
```

Giving an output like:

```
t1   2
t2   1
t3   3
```

The output should be a total for each column. The values for `t` are in the thousands, so I can't manually specify `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, etc.

Comment: You need to provide more info. For example, if the cells only have a, b or also a collection. If it's just one value each, things get a lot simpler. Also, I am guessing that the output is a total with one per column, but you need to say that.

Comment: @576i Updated, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is in **df**,
first lets get the column names into a variable

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('t')]
```

Now let's do the first delimitation.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
sum1 = df.loc[df.item1 == df.item2][cols].applymap(lambda x: d.get(x, 0)).sum()
```

Now let's do the second delimitation

```
d = {'c': 1, 'd': 2}
sum2 = df.loc[df.item1 == df.item3][cols].applymap(lambda x: d.get(x, 0)).sum()
```

Add for result

```
result = sum1 + sum2
print(result)
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do I use `c.startswith('t')` with multiple values? I should have specified, some columns start with `n` or `y`. 2) Can I just define `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}` then define the sums?   Thanks!

Comment: 1.) df.colums gets the column names. if you can't do startswith, any other python idea will work. Maybe use `c[0] in ('n','y')`It's a normal Python list. For example, use df.colums[2:] to take any but the first two. 2.) yes, your example didn't specify that a or b should count for the second delimitation, if your real example works like that, fine. In general you should just test this with a smaller, real dataset and look at the values...

Comment: How would I save this to a file? When I try np.savetext, it only gives me the numerical values, not the `cols` that match each value.

Comment: Try for example `result.to_csv('yourname.csv')`. But this would be a new question "How do I save a pandas dataframe or series to csv?"